# Fixed height columns with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to set the height of all 3 columns to be the height of the tallest column in my grid. This will change on a page-by-page basis, so is there a way to do this without setting an actual `min-height` value?

https://jsfiddle.net/t7v5x48q/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
<div style="background: #eaeaea; padding: 10px;"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" alt="" /></a>
<p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis faucibus dui, a malesuada nibh sagittis ut. Nunc mauris velit, rutrum id lobortis nec, ornare in diam. Nullam iaculis sem non mollis fermentum. Morbi pellentesque.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
<div style="background: #eaeaea; padding: 10px;"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" alt="" /></a>
<p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis faucibus dui, a malesuada nibh sagittis ut. Nunc mauris velit, rutrum id lobortis nec, ornare in diam. Nullam.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
<div style="background: #eaeaea; padding: 10px;"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" alt="" /></a>
<p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis faucibus dui, a malesuada nibh sagittis ut. Nunc mauris velit, rutrum id lobortis nec.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to use javascript for that..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: try using bootstrap 4  flexgrid option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that you should check the heights of the columns you are interested in, with something like [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) and then apply the greatest of them to all of them with `element.style.height`

Another way is to use the CSS flex model, in which case you won't need JavasScript

Here is a very naive implementation of what you want to achieve, based on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t7v5x48q/3/ (notice I also added a CSS rule, in addition to the JS)

Comment: Hi Mitch, could you possibly show me how to do this with my example? I'm not terribly great with Javascript so a little help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk I updated my answer, added a fiddle, hope it helps